# what is container inventory in azure kubernetes service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, devops, azure-aks

I am analyzing azure kubernetes service data ingestion to the log analytics and cost optimization.

When i analyze the logs using queries i found that container inventory produces large data ingestion to log analytics which costs more.

When I analyzed about container inventory for AKS, kubernetes i couldn't find proper answer.

Can anyone explain what is container inventory? and how it generates so much of data ingestion in aks?how can i optimize container inventory data ingestion?

I analyzed more about this concept but i couldn't get proper explanation about it as i fresh to azure AKS and kubernetes. can anyone guide me on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ContainerIventory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/containerinventory) is an inventory of all the containers running in the cluster and their properties) such as state, ports, environment variables etc).

The inventory is collected periodically ([once every minute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-cost#cluster-inventory)). This means that all this data is collected every minute for every container.

To reduce data ingestion and cost, there are a few things you can do, which are described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-cost#controlling-ingestion-to-reduce-cost), for example disable the environment variable collection, which can be done by either disabling log collection globally in the oms agent config map:

```
[log_collection_settings.env_var]
    enabled = false
```

Or by [disabling it per container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-manage-agent#how-to-disable-environment-variable-collection-on-a-container) by setting the environment variable `AZMON_COLLECT_ENV` to false

Comment: Thanks for the guidence and it helps me lot simply....!!!Can you tell me one more thing that i have only two nodes in the AKS and when i analyze about the node billable data ingestion i found that one more node is included along with two nodes which shows me 'deprecate field: see http://aka'. And it also ingest some billable data. Asusal i stucked after analyzing available node and aks cluster and some google docs. i want to get rid that  'deprecate field: see http://aka' node which ingest billable log. If you have any idea please guide me

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, but nodes can come and go in a Kubernetes cluster. Even if you have only two nodes at any given point in time, a scaling event (or a node crash) can make more node ids show up in the logs (for example if a crashed node is replaced)

Comment: How can I edit these settings of the config map? in the portal, I tried to go to aks cluster and in the left pane, I choose configurations and look for the above lines in oms agent YAML config but cannot find these lines. in which config these lines present and how can I edit this?

Comment: Please see the instruction for [Configure and deploy ConfigMaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-agent-config#configure-and-deploy-configmaps)

Comment: I already referred this document brother. Can i edit the configmap as mention here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-portal'. I tried this method but i dont know in which configmap stdout and stderr logging or configured. I want to know where are these config

Comment: @jayaprakashR As mentioned in the link i posted above, First you need to create the config map if it does not exist. The documentation also contains a yaml representation of an example config map, where you can see that it is called `container-azm-ms-agentconfig` and deployed in the namespace `kube-system`

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. I don't have ```container-azm-ms-agentconfig``` and instead i have ```container-azm-ms-aks-k8scluster``` and ```omsagent-rs-config``` files at ```kube-system``` namespace. But I don't find any logging configuration in these files. My doubt is, To disable logging do I need to create that file? or do I need to find it somewhere else?. And if I need to create this file then where the logging details are saved before?

Comment: Another doubt is that I already have a configmap for deployment which doesn't have below logging information. can I add below config to disable data ingestion? will it affect any deployment if I add his logging information in existing configmap?
```[log_collection_settings.env_var]
 enabled = false```

Comment: No, you cannot add this line to any config map. It needs to be to the specific config map that the oms agent uses.

The instructions on [Configure and deploy ConfigMaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-agent-config#configure-and-deploy-configmaps) contains a concrete three step list that explains in detail how you create and deploy this config map. **Can you please be more specific in what is unclear in those instructions**?

Comment: Thanks for the info. In the link you sent there they create ```container-azm-ms-agentconfig``` configmap file. Do I also need to create that separate file to disable the logging as mentioned in that doc? if yes then where will be the below logging information that was used before?  i hope you understand my question.
```[log_collection_settings.env_var]  enabled = false```

Comment: Yes, you would need to create that config map in the `kube-system` namespace if it does not already exists. If it does not exist it means that there are no configuration specified and default values are utilized. You can see what the default values are in the same document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-agent-config#data-collection-settings

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer brother!!! I am gonna implement it and if any doubts will come back

Comment: Can you suggest to me one solution, please? That, in another account we didn't configure any configmap and we don't have any server connection with that cluster. means we cant configure any omsagent configmap as you suggest in previous comments. That also consumes cost for data ingestion. for this scenario how can I disable the logging? how can I configure omsagent configmap for that aks cluster?